Why does IMake write temporary executable files during a build?
Using a command such as the following, I can monitor file creation within the temp directory and I can see that IMake generates temp files with executable permissions while building a native C++ project.
watch -n0,1 "ls -lrt . 2>&1 | tee -a watch.txt"

grep rwx watch.txt
-rwx--x--x. 1 user-name view 25768 Apr 11 10:32 imakeoKeM9W
-rwx--x--x. 1 user-name view 25768 Apr 11 10:32 imake5kr4ns

This is a problem on hardened linux systems that don't allow executable files in the system temp directory. Now I know IMake is old technology but for now our team needs to continue using it for project that has existed for over a decade. Does anyone know why Imake does this and how it could be changed?  The only work around I have found is to override the $TMPDIR in the shell that the build runs within so that the temp files are written somewhere else.  I assume it is imake doing this since the prefix is imake so I don't think that it is gnu make doing this.

It's not GNU Make.  However, GNU Make will also write its own files to a temp directory, as will many other tools.  In short trying to run a build where the system temp directory is not writable, is simply not going to work in general although it may work for specific curated environments.  If you don't want to write to the system temp directory, you should create your own "safe" temp directory and set the appropriate environment variables so your build environment can use it.

Although I do agree that writing executable files is not usual, some tools may be creating named pipes and other things here which might have unusual permissions.
